# How to find closest record in two tables based on creation date?

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I have two tables that are related by user_id, and I need to join these tables with the following conditions:

- First, they should be related to their own user
- Second, for each record in the first table, it should choose the corresponding record in the second table which has the closest creation date to the first one.

Consider these two tables:

###### table_1

| id | user_id | name | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | A | 2023-01-01 12:00:00 |
| 2 | 11 | B | 2023-01-01 12:08:00 |
| 3 | 22 | C | 2023-01-01 13:00:00 |
| 4 | 33 | D | 2023-01-01 14:00:00 |

###### table_2

| id | user_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 2023-01-01 12:05:00 |
| 2 | 22 | 2023-01-01 13:03:00 |
| 2 | 22 | 2023-01-01 13:06:00 |
| 3 | 33 | 2023-01-01 14:12:00 |

###### expected result

| id | user_id | name | created_at | t2_created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | A | 2023-01-01 12:00:00 | 2023-01-01 12:05:00 |
| 2 | 11 | B | 2023-01-01 12:08:00 | null |
| 3 | 22 | C | 2023-01-01 13:00:00 | 2023-01-01 13:03:00 |
| 4 | 33 | D | 2023-01-01 14:00:00 | 2023-01-01 14:12:00 |

Comment: Why not test your ideas, and see if they work?

Comment: Use a lateral join to a correlated subquery.

Comment: @MikeOrganek can you make an example? Because I have no idea how to do that!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lateral join behaves like a foreach loop.  The following works in PostgreSQL.  It is a left join lateral to deal with `name` 'B' in your sample results.  A cross join lateral does not return that row.

```
select t1.*, t2.created_at as t2_created_at
  from table_1 t1
       left join lateral (select user_id, created_at
                             from table_2
                            where user_id = t1.user_id
                              and created_at >= t1.created_at
                            order by created_at
                            limit 1) t2
         on true;
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2pXaarst)